# importing osm file into a postgres/postgis database

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, phppgadmin

Im using the tool osm2pgsql to import an osm file into a postgres database using phppgadmin as the administrative tool. i have only downloaded a small town from osm in xml format and im having trouble importing it using the terminal on mac. Im a bit of a noob at this so any help would be greatly appreciated. Ive looked at several articles but none provide the clarity i need in order to fulfill my needs.

Thanks

im getting this error could be something small not sure..

```
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skipping
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('planet_osm_point', 'way', 900913, 'POINT', 2 );
 failed: ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, integer, unknown,     integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('planet_osm_point', 'way', 900913, ...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the postgis extensions into your postgres database. Assuming that you have postgis installed on your machine you need to do something like:

```
psql <database> < /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql
```

The exact path to `postgis.sql` will depend on the distribution you are using and how it has packaged postgis. You may also want/need to install the spatial reference systems table with a command like this:

```
psql <database> < /usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

Comment: i executed those sql files and i now have all the functions required. thanks for that btw. im still not sure how to do the import with osm2pgsql. Thanks

Comment: When I try to execute `postgis.sql` I get the error `Type "spheroid" already exists`. How can I fix it?

Comment: In postgresql 9 and postgis 2 versions this is done by: CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology; [more info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/)

Comment: In addition to Javier Mr, check this link: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS/Installation#Activate_PostGIS

Answer (score 1):

This is an example command:

osm2pgsql -c -d your_country -U postgres -W -H localhost -P 5432 -s -k -x -p osm -S default.style ..\your_country.osm.bz2

Here are some useful weblinks:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql
http://www.gis.hsr.ch/wiki/Osm2pgsql

-S.