# Error at importing osm file into a postgres database

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, postgis, tilemill

I am using `osm2psql` to import an osm file into a `postgres` database using the following command:

`osm2pgsql -cGs -d osm -S /usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style ~/Downloads/your_file.osm.pbf`

When I run it in terminal I get the following error:

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro:Downloads rjth$ osm2pgsql -cGs -d osm -S
/usr/local/share/osm2pgsql/default.style ~/Downloads/vienna-bratislava.osm.pbf
osm2pgsql SVN version 0.84.0 (64bit id space)
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point" does not exist, skippin
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('planet_osm_point', 'way', 900913, 'POINT', 2 );
failed: ERROR:  function addgeometrycolumn(unknown, unknown, integer, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AddGeometryColumn('planet_osm_point', 'way', 900913, ...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Error occurred, cleaning up
```

I have already tried [TomH suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546373/importing-osm-file-into-a-postgres-postgis-database) for a similar question and I have followed every step of the [official tilemill documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/#osm2pgsql). for the installation option of postgis I have installed [postgresapp](http://postgresapp.com/).

Comment: Is sure looks like `create extension postgis;` either was not done, or failed.  If you think that it was done, can you show us the output of the psql session in which you created the postgis extension?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

If `create extension postgis` was done, then it wasn't with the database `osm`.

You need to add the extension within the osm database.

```
rjth$ psql osm
osm=# create extension postgis;
```

Then run your command to access the osm.pbf file and it should work.